# Java - How do I implement sliding window for program

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, sliding-window

I am struggling with how to implement **sliding windows** to the following problem below.

I am writing a program that should ask the location of a file (which has the digits of PI) and the number of digits to parse via the Scanner class from user.

Problem:
A company is evaluating if it can assign phone numbers by parsing the number of PI after decimal digits. Assume each phone number has 5 digits. So the first 5 digits after the decimal point for the first phone number, the 5 digits starting from the second position form the second phone number (it follows a sliding window pattern where you slide one digit at a time).

- If all the phone numbers are unique, then the program should print "Task success, all phone numbers are unique."
- However, if not, then it should print "Phone numbers are repeated". Also the total phone numbers generated should be printed. The program should be able to read 100,000 digits of PI.

Below is my attempt so far.

How can the sliding window be implemented?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


public class Problem3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream inputstream = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            System.out.println("Give the location of the file (example: C:\\Users\\Onur\\workspace\\ProgAssign3\\src\\pi.txt):");
            String fileloc = input.nextLine();

            inputstream = new FileInputStream(fileloc);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            String stringinput;

            System.out.println("Number of digits of PI to parse: ");
            int parsenum = input.nextInt() + 2;
            String[] stringarray = new String[parsenum];

            while((stringinput = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringinput = stringinput.substring(2, parsenum);

                for(int i = 0; i < stringinput.length(); i++) {
                    stringarray = stringinput.split("");
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                set.add(stringarray[i]);
            }

            System.out.println(set);

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.err.println("File not found, please try again");
            main(null);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Invalid input entered");
        }
        finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see anything to do with pi anyway.  You are just reading several digits from a text file full of digits, isn't it?  And I cannot find your question.  What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle the "sliding window" would be to use a [**RandomAccessFile**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), and seek to the current offset.

The uniqueness can be handled by a [**Set**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class NumberGeneratorPI {

    private static final int N = 100_000;
    private static final String PI = "pi.txt"; // 1415...
    private static final byte[] buf = new byte[5];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Set<String> numbers = new HashSet<>();
        RandomAccessFile digits = new RandomAccessFile(new File(PI), "r");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            digits.seek(i);
            digits.read(buf);
            if (!numbers.add(new String(buf)))
                System.out.println("Duplicate!");
        }
        // Do something with numbers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea what the problem you are facing.  In psuedo code it should look something like this:

```
ask for file name;
open inputStream for file;

read 5 characters from inputStream;
phoneNumber = concatenation of 5 character

print phoneNumber;
put phoneNumber in a set;

while (there are more data in inputStream) {
    c = read 1 char from inputStream;
    phoneNumber = substring of phoneNumber from 2nd to end, plus c;
    print phoneNumber;
    if (phoneNumber exists in set) {
          print it is repeated;
    } else {
          add phoneNumber to set;
    }
}
```